# Create a list of recently added movies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

On my app users can enter a movie title into a search field and the app shows a result of all the movies that correspond to the query, then the user can click on a "add movie" button and add that movie to their front page.

For my next feature I'm trying to create an list of recently added movies. For this I've created a new template called "Suggestions".

My initial thinking was to use the following code in my new suggestions template,

```
.movie_container{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movies | orderBy:'id':true"}
```

This does show the most recently added movies in the correct order, but it only shows the movies added by the user and not a general list of all the movies added by all the users.

So if user 1 adds a movie, user 2 doesn't see it in the suggestion template. This is because I've added a column "user_id" to my movies table so that when a user adds a movie it only shows up in his overview. This is the opposite of what I want for this feature.

What would be a good way to get around this problem? Is it possible using AngularJS to retrieve all the movies in the movie model or do I have to change something in my rails configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have already taken care of persisting the added Movies.
Probably you just need to look at the fetching of the records that populate your "most recently added movies"-List.

Probably a change from

```
@user.movies
```

to

```
Movie.all
```

should work fine

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, I want 2 features. One feature to only show the movies the user added, and one feature that shows all the movies added. If I would change my Rails controller, it would just show all the movies everywhere. Right?

Comment: Well it depends on which variable populates the movies variable you're using in your ng-repeat statement. You could use two seperate variables, one for all movies added, another one for user-created movies.

Comment: That's the problem. I use the same method to populate both features, that's where the problem is comming from. I don't think creating another Rails controller just for this feature is the right way to go. By the way, I use `respond_with current_user.movies` in my movies_controller.rb

Comment: You are right, it's probably not. I mean you could probably use a list of all movies and filter the user-created list by user-id of the currently logged in user. Otherwise you need to do two requests probably.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing to filter out all the movies that don't have the same user_id. Going to see if I can find some info on that.